# Multiple foreach with over 37 million possibilities

Tags: php, arrays

I've been tasked with creating a list of all possibilities using data in 8 blocks.

The 8 blocks have the following number of possibilities:

```
*Block 1: 12 possibilities
*Block 2: 8 possibilities
*Block 3: 8 possibilities
*Block 4: 11 possibilities
*Block 5: 16 possibilities
*Block 6: 11 possibilities
*Block 7: 5 possibilities
*Block 8: 5 possibilities
```

This gives a potential number of 37,171,200 possibilities.

I tried simply doing and limiting only to displaying the values returned with the correct string length like so:

```
foreach($block1 AS $b1){
    foreach($block2 AS $b2){
        foreach($block3 AS $b3){
            foreach($block4 AS $b4){
                foreach($block5 AS $b5){
                    foreach($block6 AS $b6){
                        foreach($block7 AS $b7){
                            foreach($block8 AS $b8){
                                if (strlen($b1.$b2.$b3.$b4.$b5.$b6.$b7.$b8) == 16)
                                {
                                    echo $b1.$b2.$b3.$b4.$b5.$b6.$b7.$b8.'<br/>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However the execution time was far too long to compute. I was wondering if anyone knew of a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Not as far as I know. But if you run this at the CLI it should complete quite quickly: `php generate.php > out.txt`.

Comment: TIP: Do it in C, computation will be much faster. Unless you have to do it in PHP....

Comment: i just didnt get why do u need to do it ?

Comment: I need to do it to create a list of potential configurations for one of our products. I used Halfer's method and it generated a 63mb file with around 3 million valid configs. Now I just need to reduce them so they can be listed on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could improve your algorithm by caching the string prefixes and remember their lengths. Then you don’t have to do that for each combination.

```
$len = 16:

// array for remaining characters per level
$r = array($len);
// array of level parts
$p = array();
foreach ($block1 AS &$b1) {
    // skip if already too long
    if (($r[0] - strlen($b1)) <= 0) continue;
    $r[1] = $r[0] - strlen($b1);
    foreach ($block2 AS &$b2) {
        if (($r[1] - strlen($b2)) <= 0) continue;
        $r[2] = $r[1] - strlen($b2);
        foreach ($block3 AS $b3) {
            // …
            foreach ($block8 AS &$b8) {
                $r[8] = $r[7] - strlen($b8);
                if ($r[8] == 0) {
                    echo implode('', $p).'<br/>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, using references in `foreach` will stop PHP using a copy of the array internally.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to store the precomputed part the concatenated string known at each of the previous lelels for later reuse, avoiding concatenating everything in the innermost loop

```
foreach($block7 AS $b7){
    $precomputed7 = $precomputed6.$b7
    foreach($block8 AS $b8){
        $precomputed8 = $precomputed7.$b8
        if (strlen($precomputed8) == 16) {
            echo $precomputed8.'<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this analogously for precedent levels. Then you could try to test at one of the higher loop level for strings that are already longer as 16 chars. You can shortcut and avoid trying out other possibilities. But beware calculating the length of the string costs much performance, maybe is the latter improvement not worth it at all, depending on the input data.

Another idea is to precalculate the lengths for each block and then recurse on the array of lengths, calculating sums should be faster than concatenating and computing the length of strings. For the Vector of indexes that match the length of 16, you can easily output the full concatenated string.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have that length requirement of 16 and assuming each (i) possibility in each (b) of the eight blocks has length x_i_b you can get some reduction by some cases becoming impossible.

For example, say we have length requirement 16, but only 4 blocks, with possibilities with lengths indicated

block1: [2,3,4]
block2: [5,6,7]
block3: [8,9,10]
block4: [9,10,11]

Then all of the possibilities are impossible since block 4's lengths are all too large to permit any combination of blocks 1 - 3 of making up the rest of the 16.

Now if you're length is really 16 that means that your (possible) lengths range from 1 to 9, assumng no 0 lengths.

I can see two ways of approaching this:

1. Greedy
2. Dynamic Programming

Perhaps even combine them. For the Greedy approach, pick the biggest possibility in all the blocks, then the next biggest etc, follow that through until you cross your threshold of 16. If you got all the blocks, then you can emit that one.

Whether or not you got on threshold or not, you can then iterate through the possibilities.

The dynamic appraoch means that you should store some of the results that you compute already. Like a selection from some of the blocks that gives you a length of 7, you don't need to recompute that in future, but you can iterate through the remaining blocks to see if you can find a combination to give you lenth 9.

**EDIT**: This is kind of like the knapsack problem but with the additional restriction of 1 choice per block per instance. Anyway, in terms of other optimizations definitely pre process the blocks into arrays of lengths only and keep a running sum at each iteration level. So you only do 1 sum per each iteration of each loop, rather than 8 sums per each iteration. Also only str concat if you need to emit the selection.

If you don't want a general solution (probably easier if you don't) then you can hand code alot of problem instance specific speedups by excluding the largest too small combination of lengths (and all selections smaller than that) and excluding the smallest too large combination of lengths (and all selections larger).

Answer (score 1):

If you can express this as a nested array, try a RecursiveIteratorIterator, http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php